# Dragging tags to favorite box doesn’t work

Tags: feature-request

When I drag a tag on the questions page from the tag list to the input field **Favorite Tags** it breaks:

[image]

The tag [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability) is changed to `httpux.stackexchange.comquestionstaggedusability`.

Comment: as a note the add boxes have autocomplete so it's pretty easy to add tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not designed to, I'm afraid. See [this post on Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30118/drag-and-drop-into-favourite-tags-adds-url-as-a-tag) and the associated response:

> There is no drag-and-drop functionality with the tags right now.
>
> What you did, and can do on most browsers, is just grab the URL of the thing and it will perform a paste right into whatever input you're going for.
>
> You can also do what you did with avatars or links. But it doesn't mean it's drag-and-drop.

Comment: Oh, okay. My fault then. It really _looks_ draggable. Shouldn’t be so hard to catch those cases per JavaScript.

Comment: Well as it's been asked on MSO you're clearly not the only person who's noticed it, so don't worry about that. While possibly a nice idea the fact that the Tags entry field is fixed in the top-right means that the only tags you could drag into it would be ones that appear in the top-half of the page. If DnD were to be implemented then the tag search field would have to float with the page. That's probably a bit OTT to be beneficial I'd guess.

Comment: You can drag links from the bottom of a page by holding the link with the mouse and moving up with the `↑` key. :D